# can regex can be configurable?

Tags: python-3.x

I have regular expression in my python code, can I move it in configuration file. Is it a good practice ?

Regards,
Girish LC

Comment: Why should be something that can be represented as a string not be stored in a configuration file?

Comment: if you want it to be user-configurable then that would be standard practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, a regular expression is just a string. You can have it as a hard-coded literal in your code, read it form a configuration file, query it from a database, you name it.